# how to transform image on hover in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on reactJs.I am using semantic ui react for this.i want to tranform image when hover.My code is:

```
<Image
    src={data.profile_photo}
    alt={data.name}
    size="massive"
    avatar
    onClick={() => this.handleGallery(this,data.username)}
    onMouseOut={() => alert('out')}
     onMouseOver={() => alert('in')}
  />
```

I am new to react. I dont know where to set hover property`{transform:scale(1.5,1.5)}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the component state, this should work. Edited to show you how each image can manage its own hovering.

```
class ImgWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {hovered: false};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        src={this.props.data.profile_photo}
        alt={this.props.data.name}
        size="massive"
        avatar
        onClick={() => this.props.handleGallery(this.props.data.username)}
        onMouseOut={() => this.setState({hovered: true})}
        onMouseOver={() => this.setState({hovered: false})}
        style={{transform: `${this.state.hovered ? 'scale(1.5,1.5)' : null}`}}
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyOtherComponent extends Component {
  ....

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <ImageWrapper data={...}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: bro it working fine nd i wanted this...but i have another doubt..this image component generated dynamically images..suppose there are 3 images..so it hovered all 3 images..i just want to hovered only on that image on which i want??

Comment: You should make a specific component containing your image and having is own state. Like so, each image wrapper will manage is own state.

Comment: can u give any refrence from where i can see or do dummy code??

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use simple css selectors for this? In scss this could be done like:

```
.my-class {
    transform:scale(1, 1);
    transition: 1s;

    &:hover {
        transform:scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
}
```